# How to allow a safe list of html tags in php?

Tags: php

I would like to allow a certain list of html elements in a php response. My website consists of a few pages with some php content. In my database i've stored a few records with some text mixed with html elements.

I'm currently escaping this content with the htmlentities function. This works well in most cases, but in this case it also sanitizes my safe html tags.

A couple of possible solutions i encountered:

### Htmlpurifier

This seems to be the best solution out there. However, htmlpurifier lacks html5 support. I really would like to use some html5 tags. In the similar posts i've encountered, this option is recommended the most.

### Strips_tags()

This is a quote i copied from the htmlpurifier comparison page

> The PHP function striptags() is the classic solution for attempting to clean up HTML. It is also the worst solution, and should be avoided like the plague. The fact that it doesn't validate attributes at all means that anyone can insert an.
>   While this can be bandaided with a series of regular expressions that strip out on[event] (you're still vulnerable to XSS and at the mercy of quirky browser behavior), striptags() is fundamentally flawed and should not be used.

Is there any good alternative you guys can recommend for allowing a list of html(5) tags? Should i use a library or not?

Might it be an idea to use bb tags?

Comment: "However, htmlpurifier lacks html5 support." — What makes you think that?

Comment: I remember you asking this same question not long ago; why did you delete it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, that's true. you suggested me to rewrite the question. So i thought it would better to delete the old, unclear question and replace it with this one.

Comment: @Quentin It doesn't accept the html5 doctype and video tag. That's what i read.

Comment: I didn't say to "rewrite" the question, I remember asking you to post an example tag, which I remember you didn't do.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it has been a long time, stranger

Comment: *Aye,* quite @DarylGill

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOMDocument (http://php.net/manual/es/class.domdocument.php) and load the HTML (http://php.net/manual/es/domdocument.loadhtml.php), despite you will get warnings for HTML5 tags so you must turn off errors.

But if you don't want to write code, or do not like the lack of support for HTML which DOMDocument has, then you can try any library from packagist that parse HTML5 (https://packagist.org/?q=parse%20html5&p=0). In this case if your are using Composer will be the easiest solution.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me. DOMDocument looks good. I have a few questions though. Is it a secure way of adding an element to the response? And do you have any experience with the performance?

Comment: I have experience with DOMDocument, but I didn't do performance metrics, it's just working as expected... I use DOMDocument to parse CKeditor output to Facebook Instant Articles format for a client. At the beggining it was somewhat difficult, but dividing a problem in small peaces makes almost every problem easy to solve. I didn't run into performance problems yet.

Answer (score -3):

this is very good list:

```
<br><p><a><strong><b><i><em><img><blockquote><code><dd><dl><hr><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><label><ul><li><span><sub><sup>
```

Comment: You appear to have misread the question. It isn't asking for a list of tags which are safe.

Comment: I really doubt that `a`, `span` and `img` tags are really safe. Probably some of others as well
See at least https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/168909/xss-inside-anchor-tag-a-without-user-interaction

Comment: <img> is NOT safe and is as dangerous as <script>. Do not allow <img> tags on your website!